# A question about the graph theory or data structure and algorithms

Tags: algorithms, graphs, data-structures

I would like to ask this question as I am not sure about the answer.

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a connected, undirected graph, and let $x,y\in V$ be two different vertices. Let $A$ be the problem of finding the shortest simple path between $x$ and $y$, and let $B$ be the problem of finding the longest simple path between $x$ and $y$. Which of the following statement about $A$ and $B$ is true?

1. Both $A$ and $B$ can be solved on polynomial time
2. $A$ is not known to be solvable in polynomial time but $B$ can be solved in polynomial time
3. $A$ can be solved in polynomial time but $B$ is not known to be solvable in polynomial time
4. It is known that both $A$ and $B$ can be solved in polynomial time
5. It is not known whether either $A$ and $B$ can be solved in polynomial time

I think option 3 is correct because the time complexity for finding the shortest path between two nodes is $O(n^2)$ but for $B$, I am not sure.

Could you please explain? Thank you so much

Comment: There is at least one correct answer. There might be multiple correct answers.

Comment: yes that's why I ask because I am not sure about my answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem $A$ can be solved in polynomial time. Problem $B$ is NP-hard.
This means that options 2 and 5 are certainly false.

We don't know whether option 1 is true. If it is true is, then P=NP.

Option 3 is currently true (but might become false in the future if P is proven to be equal to NP).

Option 4 is currently false but might become true in the future (if P is proven to be equal to NP).

If we live in a world where P=NP then both option 1 and option 3 are currently true.